# Android:Running an application continously in background even if user closes the application

Tags: android

I am new to android and I was trying out an app as "Scheduled messaging".
Scenario:
Suppose you want to send some message to your friend at 6PM.
Then you can just make an entry and message will be sent automatically at that time.
But now where I am stuck up is that the application must run always even if user tries to close it because else message wont be sent.
Can anyone please give me a small demo for this.
thanks!!!

Comment: You should use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which run in background even if activity is not running....

Comment: Priyank can you please give me a short demo for this...
plzzz...

Comment: These are tow service examples...[ServicesDemo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)...&...[Service example](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/simple-example-of-service-in-android.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could run your task as a service. Or preferably  use an alarm. Have a look at the AlarmManager System Service

Comment: TanjaV-I did refer to a lot of examples of AlarmManager but none of them worked properly..
It would be great if you could just provide a small demo...

Comment: @vicky99, do you want us to code for you ? show me a code that you tried but not working properly. i know AlarmManager class & Services little bit, so i can help you :)